# cannot resolve symbol 'chromium'

Tags: java, android-studio, trusted-web-activity

I am trying to use Trusted Web Activity, following this guide : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/using-twa

I did follow all the steps, but there are several words Android Studio cannot resolve by itself and I do not find any solution. The main problem seems to be org.chromium .

In bold the words it can't resolve :

in TwaSessionHelper.java :

> import org.**chromium**.customtabsclient.shared.ServiceConnection;
>
> import org.**chromium**.customtabsclient.shared.ServiceConnectionCallback;
>
> ...
>
> public class TwaSessionHelper implements **ServiceConnectionCallback**
>   {
>
> ...
>
> mConnection = new **ServiceConnection**(this);

in TwaLauncherActivity.java :

> setContentView(R.layout.**activity_twa_launcher**);

and in the few lines of code :

> TwaSessionHelper.TwaSessionCallback twaSessionCallback = **mTwaSessionCallback**.get();

What am I missing ?

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "didi.a8bitpocketwrestlers"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.+'
}
```

Comment: Have you imported the library `com.android.support:customtabs` like the example app does? Please update your question and show your gradle file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio cannot resolve **ServiceConnectionCallback** class because a `com.android.support:customtabs` library does not contain/provide it. This class exists only in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/shared/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsclient/shared/ServiceConnectionCallback.java) and no any maven repository. So you not able to add a dependency on it in your **build.gradle** file, you have to download it and add it in your project manually.

From [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client) download only **[shared](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/tree/master/shared)** directory, [add it in your project as a module](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=how%20to%20add%20module%20in%20android%20studio&oq=how%20to%20add%20module%20in%20&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.8898j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

In your application build.gradle file add a dependency on the **shared** module.

```
compile project(':shared')
```

Comment: Thanks, it is almost solved. It still can't resolve mTwaSessionCallback though.

Comment: Do you have this field in your class? private WeakReference<TwaSessionCallback> mTwaSessionCallback;